# How do I create a vector of Location?

Tags: android, vector, location

I have an app that gets periodic location updates from google services. That is working fine.
Now, I want to store every position in a vector of positions:

```
Vector vectorLocations = new Vector();
```

onLocationChanged I do this to add the new location:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    latitud.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
    longitud.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    tiempo.setText(mLastUpdateTime);
    velocidad.setText(String.valueOf(location.getSpeed()));
    altura.setText(String.valueOf(location.getAltitude()));
    vectorLocations.addElement(location); 
    ntextView.setText(String.valueOf(vectorLocations.lastIndexOf(location)));

}
```

But now I want to get for example Location 3, so I do:

```
Location positionthree = vectorLocations.elementAt(3);
```

But I get the error incompatible types:

[image]

Comment: ¿Why do we use non English punctuation with a question written in English?

Comment: Probably because he is a native Spanish speaker, given his surname, from Argentina and he just did it automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I'm from Spain.

Comment: Do any of the given answers work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is that an `Object` is found instead of a `Location`, you could just cast the Object to a Location like so:

```
Location positionthree = (Location) vectorLocations.elementAt(3);
```

Or a simpler way is just creating an `ArrayList` of `Location` variables and accessing them. Here is something you could do:

```
ArrayList<Location> allLocations = new ArrayList<>();
// On location change
allLocations.add(location);

// When you want to access them
Location positionThree = allLocations.get(3);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is the second solution better than the first one?

Comment: Whichever solution works for you is the best one, I'd go with this answer if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the object returned by the `elementAt()` to location type like below

```
 Location positionthree = (Location) vectorLocations.elementAt(3);
```

Comment: 2004 called, and mumbled something about generics.

Answer (score -1):

It is better off using ArrayList.

Declaration:

```
ArrayList<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();
```

To add element:

```
locations.add(location);
```

To access element at position:

```
Location positionThree = locations.get(3);
```

But remember that the index 3 inside the function .get() actually refers to the position 4 as the indexes start by 0.